# How to handle watching of a reactive/non-reactive value as short as possible?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a list dropdown component that accepts `items` props which could be a reactive or non-reactive object/array.
So I `watch` it to react when the items change. But when I provide a static non-reactive array/object it issues warning that non-reactive value is provided for `watch()`. Yes, I don't care watching a non-reactive value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [`toValue`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#tovalue) utility as getter for your watcher (requires vue +3.3):

```js
watch(()=>toValue(items),(newItems)=>{
// your process
})
```

Comment: items is a reactive, seems i need is isProxy(). anyway upvoting for pointing me

Comment: what about [isreactive](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#isreactive)